# Is it ok to use "who" in this case?

Tags: who

I need help to verify if this sentence is correct. The original sentence was:

> Please provide contact details below of a person within the organization who is legally permitted to verify your employment.

But then I was asked to add "or department" and now the sentence is:

> Please provide contact details below of a person or department within the organization who is legally permitted to verify your employment.

I'm thinking that the use of "who" is not appropriate here. It doesn't sound right.

Comment: Perhaps you could replace “who” with “that”?

Comment: Of course you could replace _who_ with _that_ in any relative clause.

Comment: You can't replace "who" with "that" in non-defining relative clauses, nor in one or two defining relative clauses. And with personal antecedents, "who" is _preferred_ over "that" when the relativized element is subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the pronoun altogether:

> Please provide contact details below of a person or department within the organization legally permitted to verify your employment.

Or you can rephrase the sentence slightly:

> Please provide contact details below of a person or department within the organization *with the legal permission* to verify your employment.

Comment: But that's not "dropping the pronoun altogether", as you put it, but replacing the relative clause with a past-participial one. Same meaning of course, but different syntax.